# What is a Viridescent Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Viridescent Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image: Viridescent Words]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Viridescent Words™,Not Viridescent Words™
Palped,Banana
Fancy,Explode
Remedial,Powerful
Enrage,Fleet
Email,Bound
Stamina,Glide
Hemiacetal,Tense
Matin,Relax
Violet,Antiquity
Aphoristic,Swell
Lathe,Burst
Soubriquet,Drawn
Indinavir,Disappear
Trove,Rush
```

Comment: At first I though "Viridescent Word" is a word I don't understand, but "Email" didn't fit in.

Comment: Nice puzzle! Headers enrage valet Emile. Avert aldermen. Appeal adverse, treacherous eclat, alate delta voter!

Comment: @MOehm Testing it out?

Comment: Let's just say the puzzle left me in a good mood. I also think the non-viridescent parts could be put to good use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Answer with the help of @Will, @M Oehm, @Glorfindel and me (Maria Deleva) :

> Viridescent words contain shades of green plus one excess letter.
>  Extra viridescent words contain at least two shades of green.
>
>  Palped - apple
>  Fancy - cyan
>  Remedial - emerald, lime
>  Email -> lime
>   Hemiacetal  - malachite, lime, teal
>   Enrage - green
>   Stamina - mantis, mint
>   Matin - mint
>   Violet - olive
>   Aphoristic - pistachio
>   Lathe - teal
>   Soubriquet = turquoise
>   Indinavir = viridian
>  Trove -  vert (@RadoslavHristov)

Comment: `aphoristic` = `pistachio`?

Comment: Remedial also contains a green type of gem (leave the `i` out).

Comment: Hemiacetal contains a mineral too, btw

Comment: And in each case it seems you only need to remove 1 letter (except for the 'extra' ones).

Comment: I think all words have just one excess letter that isn't green.

Comment: Fancy => cyan, Palped => apple

Comment: also `lathe` = `teal`, `soubriquet` = `turquoise`, `indinavir` = `viridian`

Comment: Hemiacetal contains malachite, as Will has already found (but not spelled) out.

Comment: I think these are not just something green but names for shades of green, although I'm not sure whether mantis is a name for a colour.

Comment: trove - vert (+ o) -> green, as a heraldic tincture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vert_(heraldry)

Comment: @MOehm [mantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_green#Mantis)

Comment: In what world is *cyan* a shade of green?  Cyan is clearly blue.  Turquoise too.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I wasn't really paying that close attention when I grabbed [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Shades_of_green)

Comment: Because it has a pear? But it doesn't follow the pattern one letter plus anagram of shade of green.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Still doesn't follow the anagram of a shade of green + 1 letter

Comment: Viridescentliterally means having a greenish hue… Hence I would say banana is the only word on the list at its definition as well, as they can be green. I don't really understand your definition of the term. Where did you come up with this meaning?

Comment: @gracey209: This is a puzzle, not an exercise in taxonomy. Someone thinks of a pattern in words that others must guess. As a convention, such words are called "X Word™", where X is supposed to give a hint towards the pattern. The pattern is usually about the words themselves, i.e. the letters, the letter forms and so on, and not about their meanings.

Comment: Oh, Thank you @MariaDeleva  I understand now! I didn't realize the site was self-made puzzles. That's why I was sort of at a loss on what the relationship is supposed to be. Maybe there was an earlier question that explained what the formula was... like you just did. Thanks!